# PRISM: Using MVVM, how to resolve or inject in a constructor objects?

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm using MVVM and PRISM. In the project, I've got a common interface called IFoo and others modules should implement this interface and registered it.

```
// Common module
public interface IFoo { }

// Module1 module
public class Foo1 : IFoo { }
```

Then when I initialize the module1, I register my type and navigate.

```
_container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<Object, View1>("View1");

var module = new Uri("View1", UriKind.Relative);
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", module);
```

View1 constructor contains viewModel, this view model has in its constructor:

```
    public ViewModel1(IFoo foo, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Until this, is okay. But later, I need to get the Foo1 from external modules. So, I set another registry to mapping name for Foo1:

```
_container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>("foo1", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

And right, it's working for me, but I don't like the idea to have two instances separated. I need to have just one, and accesing to the same instance.

Is there a way to fix this scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Anyway, I attach a Zip where contains a demo which represents my problem.
http://www.mediafire.com/?feod8x0b952457e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register all your types in the bootstrapper when you load the modules.

```
// register all modules
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    // get all module types
    var types = new List<Type>();
    types.Add(typeof(ModuleA));
    types.Add(typeof(ModuleB));
    types.Add(typeof(ModuleC));

    // register all types
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo()
        {
            ModuleName = type.Name,
            ModuleType = type.AssemblyQualifiedName
        });
    }
}
```

Then in `ConfigureContainer` you map all the types and/or instances you want to access later on. The configured container is passed into your constructor for Module1Module.

```
// register all types in all modules
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();

    // ModuleA
    Container.RegisterType<IInterface1, Type1>();
    Container.RegisterType<IInterface2, Type2>();

    // ModuleB
    Container.RegisterInstance<IInterface3>("name", new Type3());
    Container.RegisterType<IInterface4, Type4>();

    // ModuleC
    Container.RegisterType<IInterface5, Type5>();
    Container.RegisterType<IInterface6, Type6>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you do need to register Foo1 twice. You're using a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` so any time you ask the Unity container for an IFoo instance, it will give you Foo1 - you don't need to use a name as a key.

So, in `module1` you register Foo1:

```
_container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(Foo1.GetHashCode());
```

And in your external module:

```
IFoo someFoo = _container.Resolve<IFoo>();

// someFoo is the same object as Foo1, so the hashcodes will be equal.
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(someFoo.GetHashCode());
```